# Possible? Two mailboxes, auto response and auto follow-up?

Tags: workflow

Here's what I'd like to do in a nutshell. I was told this could work through sharepoint, but wasn't really given any detail on exactly how.

**MailboxA** receives an e-mail from an outside contact and is requesting information. MailboxA then sends an automatic reply to the aforementioned outside contact (this part is already happening).

Here's what we'd like to accomplish.

**MailboxB** looks at all e-mails received in the last 24 hours and sends a follow-up e-mail to these outside contacts to garner feedback.

1. Is this even possible with Sharepoint?
2. How would I go about this?

I'm a complete neophyte when it comes to Sharepoint but I do the reading and researching if I can just get a feel for whether or not this is even possible. Any more details needed, I'm happy to provide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your mailboxes sharepoint libraries? If so just use retention on mailboxA to send an email after 1 day

Comment: As it is, MailboxA is a regular exchange mailbox, and not a sharepoint library. MailboxB isn't created yet but I wanted to see if it was possible. We could convert MailboxA to a sharepoint library. Any links as a place to start on how to create these sharepoint libraries? I'm going to do some digging tonight anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Carried on from the comments section:

1. Create a SMTP virtual on your SP server (make sure that exchange allows email to go to this server, talk to your system admin if this doesn't work)
2. Central Admin -> Incoming Email Options -> Set domain name among other options you want
3. Create a Library in SP as normal and under options allow incoming email and give it an email address.
4. Create a 2010 workflow to send an email.
5. Add retention logic to start the workflow after 1 day (Library settings - Information management - retention)

For help on how to set up incoming emails Technet has a few good articles (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc262947.aspx), but there are many blogs out there that cover this.